# How to modify the zones width in a “One column with sidebar” Text Layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a team site page and I am using the “One Column with sidebar” Text layout. But I need to minimize the width of the Side bar and expand the width of the One column. I tried accessing the zone html info from the SharePoint designer but cannot locate where I can find the Zones info inside SharePoint designer 2013.

The sidebar contain Useful links only and it is consuming a lot of unused space as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In general you would override the styles of the containers (div elements usually) that are present in master page. Rather than accessing the zones. In most cases zones would expand and contract depending upon higher level containers.

Comment: yes i want to access the zones info from the styles ...or from the master page .

Comment: and in my case how i can reduce the width size of my sidebar ? as it i consuming unused free space ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use developer toolbar to observe the container/zone and the corresponding style. That would be really quick

Comment: can you explain your point more please.